# Show loading indicator while graph is loading in Highcharts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, highcharts, swift3

I am generating a graph using Highcharts framework in one of the iOS projects using Swift language.

The function for generating graph is as follows.

```
   private func createBUGraph()
{
    let chartView = HIChartView(frame: self.chartHolderViewOutlet.bounds)
    

    let options = HIOptions()
    

    let title = HITitle()
    title.text = "UTS"
    options.title = title
    let subtitle = HISubtitle()
    subtitle.text = "Sales & Margin"
    options.subtitle = subtitle
    
    let xAxis = HIXAxis()
    xAxis.categories = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]//
    options.xAxis = [xAxis]

    let yAxis = HIYAxis()
    //yAxis.min = 0
    yAxis.title = HITitle()
    yAxis.title.text = "Sales"
    yAxis.lineWidth = 1
    

    let y2Axis = HIYAxis()
    y2Axis.title = HITitle()
    y2Axis.title.text = "Margin"
    y2Axis.lineWidth = 1
    y2Axis.tickPositions = [5,10,15,20]
    y2Axis.opposite = true
    options.yAxis = [yAxis,y2Axis]
    
    
    let Sales = HIColumn()
    Sales.name = "Sales"
    Sales.data = [3, 2, 1, 3]

    let SalesForecast = HIColumn()
    SalesForecast.name = "Sales Forecast"
    SalesForecast.data = 2, 3, 5, 7]
    
    let Margin = HISeries()
    Margin.name = "Margin"
    Margin.data = [2.5, 1.2, 8.5, 5.5]
    Margin.marker = HIMarker()
    Margin.marker.lineWidth = 2
    Margin.marker.symbol = "circle"
   
    
    let MarginForeast = HISeries()
    MarginForeast.name = "Margin Foreast"
    MarginForeast.data = [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33] //
    MarginForeast.marker = HIMarker()
    MarginForeast.marker.lineWidth = 2
    MarginForeast.marker.symbol = "circle"
    
    
    options.series = [Sales, SalesForecast, Margin, MarginForeast]

    chartView.options = options
    
    self.chartHolderViewOutlet.addSubview(chartView)
}
```

While the graph is being loaded, I need to show a loading indicator in the graph. Is there any way to show that?

Or is there any way to know whether the graph has completed loading or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add any loader when ever you call Chart method and stop loader when your charts load.

These are library for loader you can use any other or by default loader by apple.

1.https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView
2.https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD

Comment: I am looking for something like a completion handler for highcharts framework.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
func createBUGraph(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
    // do stuff here 
    completion(true)
}
    
createBUGraph(completion: { (success) -> Void in
    // add loader
    if success {
        print("true")
        // hide loader
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use your own loader and show it when the chart is loading.
Then you can hide it using the `chartViewDidLoad` function from `HIChartViewDelegate`

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/ios/highcharts/Protocols/HIChartViewDelegate.html#//api/name/chartViewDidLoad

Comment: I tried using the delegate function as mentioned in the document. But somehow the delegate function is not getting called.